# Return true when more than 0% of element is in viewport / window

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, the below code returns true when the element given as a argument is fully in the viewport / window.

How can I change it so that it returns true when any bit, or anything more than 0%, of an element is in the viewport?

```
function isElementInViewport(el){
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        return(
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document. documentElement.clientHeight) && 
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document. documentElement.clientWidth)
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `top` and `bottom`, and swap `left` and `right`.

```
function isElementInViewport(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.bottom >= 0 &&
        rect.right >= 0 &&
        rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document. documentElement.clientHeight) && 
        rect.left <= (window.innerWidth || document. documentElement.clientWidth);
}
```

Demo here: [jsfiddle.net/w7ApB](http://jsfiddle.net/w7ApB/)